# from elements in a line to key and values

Tags: python

I have a file with lines like this:

```
no.3   normal   yes   54   0,543    12
```

And I should end up with `("normal", yes, 54, 0.543, 12)` when I `print info(no.3)`

I have started by splitting up in lines. But now I'm not sure what to do?

As I can see, I need to use the first element as key, and the remaining as value.
But I'm not sure where to start?

Comment: Please post the code you already have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mydict = {}
for line in myfile:
   items = line.split()          # split line on whitespace
   mydict[items[0]] = items[1:]  # first item: key, rest: values
```

Then you can do

```
print mydict["no.3"]
```

and get

```
['normal', 'yes', '54', '0,543', '12']
```